# Mule 4 : Dataweave : how to do the below transformation?

Tags: dataweave, mule4

Please help with the below transformation

Input :

```
[{"id":1,"sub":["tamil"]},{"id":2,"sub":["english","maths"]},{"id":3,"sub":["phy","che"]}]
```

Output:

````
[
{"id":1,"sub":"tamil"},
{"id":2,"sub":"english"},
{"id":2,"sub":"maths"},
{"id":3,"sub":"phy"},
{"id":3,"sub":"che"}
]```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following DataWeave expression:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
flatten(payload map ((item1, index) -> 
    flatten(item1.sub map ((item2, index) -> {
        "id": item1.id,
        "sub": item2
    })
)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was having difficulty to get Id value inside nested map. Will remember this trick of item1 and item

Comment: You should have mentioned that in your question for context. You can use the default parameters for map(), mapObject(), filter(), etc ($, $$) but for nested mappings it is better to name them to avoid confusions.